# Access 2007 parsing with a special character for a delimiter

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a data field that uses an @ sign to designate one data value to a broader data set. It is similar but not equivalent to an e-mail, "john@example.com". The information to the left of the first @ is what I want, but I can't seem to get the `Instr()` function to return the correct index for the `@`. When I create a column for `Instr(1,[DataSet],"[@]")`, I get a column full of 0's. It is important to note that all data in the column I am addressing has an `@` symbol.

I have read that access does not handle special characters well, but I am at a loss as to a workaround for my problem. I bracketed the special characters inside the quotations, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. For reference, a few example values to parse would be:

```
MSE3.7 305ST 305@2000 275@3000 notes and things here
MGT5.0 505ST 2013 505@1800 450@2600 other notes w/comments
```

As you can tell, there are no constants besides the 'at sign' for me to delimit (there are around 400 of these different values), which is the root of my problem if I can't get the query to work as-is.

Looking forward to hearing about past experience/workarounds.

edit:
My full query is below:

```
SELECT First([QRY_ENGINES_2012-YTD].EngineOptionCd) AS [EngineOptionCd Field], Count([QRY_ENGINES_2012-YTD].EngineOptionCd) AS NumberOfDups, Option.OptionDes, InStr(1,[EngineOptionCd],"[@]") AS [Engine Horsepower] INTO [TBL_2012-13YTD_ENGINES]
FROM [QRY_ENGINES_2012-YTD] INNER JOIN Option ON [QRY_ENGINES_2012-YTD].EngineOptionCd = Option.OptionCd
GROUP BY Option.OptionDes, [QRY_ENGINES_2012-YTD].EngineOptionCd, InStr(1,[EngineOptionCd],"[@]")
HAVING (((Count([QRY_ENGINES_2012-YTD].EngineOptionCd))>1) 
    AND ((OptionDes) Like "*" & "MST" & "*" And (OptionDes) Not Like "*" & "MST12" & "*" And (OptionDes) Not Like "*" & "11.9" & "*")) OR (((OptionDes) Like "*" & "GT" & "*"));
```

I edited some names to provide anonymity. It started as a "find duplicates" query, but I wanted to parse some of the information included. Maybe that's the issue? Need to create a separate query?

Edit: The issue was that I was referencing the wrong field in my code.

Comment: if I do `instr(1,"305@2000","@")` I get 4. You do not need to escape `@`. Can you post your full query? I suspect the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I ran the same test as Brad with the same result. But your post mentions @, then asterisk, then ampersand. I'm puzzled as to why you may have mentioned all these, or were these just mistakes in your post?

Comment: @AndyG, I got mixed up in the terminology for the damn symbol. Any time I say asterisk or ampersand, I mean `@`. I edited it to reflect this.

Comment: @Brad, I uploaded the code. I was lazy by trying to add this onto an existing "find ducplicates" query. Perhaps that was too lazy and I needed to separate it into another query?

Comment: I found the solution. I was referencing the wrong field. Huge screw up on my part. I needed to use EngineOptionDes, not EngineOptionCd. I feel very dumb and I am sorry to have wasted your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discard the square brackets around the `@` symbol in the third argument to `InStr`.

Consider this example from the Immediate window.  The first 2 examples look for the position of the string, *"[@]"*, within the first string.

```
? InStr(1, "john@example.com", "[@]")
 0 
? InStr(1, "john[@]example.com", "[@]")
 5 
? InStr(1, "john@example.com", "@")
 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Option is a reserved word. Escape it

```
SELECT First([QRY_ENGINES_2012-YTD].EngineOptionCd) AS [EngineOptionCd Field]
, Count([QRY_ENGINES_2012-YTD].EngineOptionCd) AS NumberOfDups
, [Option].OptionDes
, InStr(1,[EngineOptionCd],"@") AS [Engine Horsepower] 
INTO [TBL_2012-13YTD_ENGINES]
FROM [QRY_ENGINES_2012-YTD] 
INNER JOIN [Option] ON [QRY_ENGINES_2012-YTD].EngineOptionCd = [Option].OptionCd
GROUP BY [Option].OptionDes, [QRY_ENGINES_2012-YTD].EngineOptionCd, InStr(1,[EngineOptionCd],"@")
HAVING (((Count([QRY_ENGINES_2012-YTD].EngineOptionCd))>1) 
    AND ((OptionDes) Like "*" & "MST" & "*" 
    And (OptionDes) Not Like "*" & "MST12" & "*" 
    And (OptionDes) Not Like "*" & "11.9" & "*"))

    OR (((OptionDes) Like "*" & "GT" & "*"));
```

Comment: "Option" is not in the actual code, that is the filler I used for the real name of my table, which includes company names. "XXX_dbo_Option"

Comment: Found the solution, which was that I was referencing the wrong field. I am horribly sorry for taking up your time.